# Розовые текстуры после компиляции

Tags: unity3d, графика, текстура

Собрал 2D игру в .арk. При запуске на 5 и ниже андроиде все текстуры розового цвета.
Раньше была такая проблема, решил её за пару секунд в настройках, то ли галочку поставил где-то, то ли переключил что-то.
Сейчас забыл, как это делается... Не могу вспомнить
Помогите, пожалуйста

Скрин:
[image: скрин]

Comment: не нашли способа решения проблемы?