# Меняется цвет 3d обьекта в unity и пропадает текст при компиляции

Tags: c#, unity3d

писал игру и возникла проблема с меню загрузки. Меню состоит из камеры, направленных на чёрные 3d панели с текстом (TextMeshPro) на них. Как это работает: сначала первые две панали прозрачны, позже появляется вторая панель с текстом, а через время и третья, перекрывая собой предыдущее. Возможно не лучшее решение, но другого не нашёл, т.к. замена текста мне не подойдёт и нужна плавная анимация. В редакторе юнити анимации проигрываются нормально, а вот при компиляции панели становятся розовыми и видно только надпись на первой от камеры панели. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема.
Скрины:
панели с текстом:
[image: панели с текстом]
демонстрация работы в демо режиме:
[image: демонстрация работы в демо режиме]
при компиляции:
[image: при компиляции]

[image: при компиляции 2]

Скрипт появления панелей:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    private void Start()
    {
        var renderer = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    renderer.material.shader = Shader.Find( "Transparent/Diffuse" );
    renderer.material.color = Color.black * 0; 
    renderer.material.color = Color.white * 0; 
    StartCoroutine(a());
}

// Update is called once per frame
private void Update()
{

}
public float x = 5.5f;
public float f;
IEnumerator a()
{   
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(x);
    x = 0.02f;
    if(f < 1)
    {
    f += 0.01f;
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.black * f; 
    }
    StartCoroutine(a());
    
}
}
```

P.s: знаю, что код можно сильно оптимизировать, но для начала надо сделать хотя бы функционал

[Розовые текстуры после компиляции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1188033/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) - скорее всего похожая проблема.

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/869037 возможно решит проблему с розовыми текстурами

Comment: Этот цвет, когда шейдер не отрендерился, ошибка, не поддерживается графическим API (в редакторе и билде они могут быть разными), все что угодно. [Error and loading shaders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/shader-error.html)